# How to build service discovery with Consul DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, consul, service-discovery, dnsmasq

I have several services packaged in a docker container. Each service will communicate with each other using the consul server which acts as the default DNS server. Where each service can communicate using **Consul's FQDN** such as (`service-a.service.consul`) or (`service-b.service.consul`).

My approach has worked by building a docker image containing my API binaries along with ***dnsmasq*** which will be used to forward DNS queries to my Consul DNS server listening on port `8600/udp` `8600/tcp` as the default configuration of Consul itself.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:
  consul-server:
    container_name: consul-server
    image: hashicorp/consul:1.15
    ports:
      - 8500:8500
      - 8600:8600
      - 8600:8600/udp
    command: "agent"
    networks:
      - sample-net

  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    image: service-a
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    networks:
      - sample-net
    depends_on:
      - consul-server
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
      - 1.0.0.1
      - 1.1.1.1

networks:
  sample-net:
    driver: bridge
```

My problem is, because I use a local DNS server on each container so that when my container makes an http request with the domain `service-*.consul.service` it can be resolved and forwarded to my Consul Server, but when I want to access the outside web like `google .com`, that I can not.

Can anyone help or give advice regarding my case?

When I remove the dns setting on my docker container

```
  service-a:
    container_name: service-a
    image: service-a
    ports:
      - 3000:80
    networks:
      - sample-net
    depends_on:
      - consul-server
```

I can also ping external websites

```
/app # ping google.com
PING google.com (216.239.38.120): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 216.239.38.120: seq=0 ttl=116 time=40.006 ms
64 bytes from 216.239.38.120: seq=1 ttl=116 time=47.230 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 36.226/41.470/47.247 ms
```

But I can't ping other services on my docker network

```
/app # ping service-a.service.consul
ping: bad address 'service-a.service.consul'
```

The same is true when I set the dns server to the container's locale ie: *127.0.0.1*, now I can ping other services using the ***Consul FQDN*** but not the external web.

```
/app # ping service-a.service.consul
PING service-a.service.consul (192.168.64.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.64.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.378 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.64.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.176 ms

--- service-a.service.consul ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.174/0.220/0.378 ms
```

My goal is to be able to communicate between services using Consul FQDN, and also outside internet networks